# Changing background across all activities with sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, onresume, setbackground

I have an Activity where i store the drawable in **SharedPreferences** and then load it in the onResume() method in the other activities to change the background.

**Like this:**

```
@Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

    int mSavedBackground = storageUtil.loadBackgroundId();

    mMainLayout.setBackgroundResource(mSavedBackground);
}
```

But is it bad to always call `.setBackgroundResource` in onResume()?

Comment: what is your actual requirement? you can call it in onCreate method.

Comment: Usually, it won't have a huge impact. Since the resource would be cached. You can also try adding it in `onCreate()` if that works for you.

Comment: It depends upon your background id resource resolution. If your background image is of very high resolution and you are calling setBackgroundResource very frequently then it will through error.

Comment: @Froyo My parentActivity doesn't get recreated because i use launchmode singletop.

Comment: @Nik My parentActivity doesn't get recreated because i use launchmode singletop

Comment: @Anjali I have a few pictures which are xhdpi 640*960, so do you think it's still acceptable to set the resource in onResume?

Comment: @Vince In case for large resolution image, you can use Image loading and caching library (ie. Glide) at onResume for efficient solution.

Comment: @Vince yes it will be fine.